# Reflect.construct() Why it is necessary override object prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

```
class Name{
    constructor(name)
    {
      this.name = name
    }
}


function greet()
{
  return "Hello World"
}

let Max = Reflect.construct(Name,["Maxi"],greet);
console.log(Max.__proto__ == greet.prototype); //true
```

Why it is necessary override object prototype

Comment: Could you expand your question? I don't feel like it is entirely clear what you are asking.

Comment: Ok 
first question 
class Name{
    constructor(name)
    {
      this.name = name
    }
}

let Max = new Name("Maxi")
let Max = Reflect.construct(Name,['Maxi'])
what is difference ?

Comment: What you are doing is like `var Max = new greet("Maxi");` That's all it is. You are just using the `greet` function as a constructor and passing the values in the array argument (the second argument) as arguments to the `greet` function.

Comment: Why use it? and why Max.__proto__ == greet.prototype return true and can i use greet method in Max object?

Comment: In order to use the `greet` method in Max object you should not fiddle with the Reflect object at all. Just do `Name.prototype.greet = n => "Hello" + n;` instead of defining the `greet` function solely like that. Then `let Max = new Name("Maxi")`

Comment: `Why use it?` The average person has zero reason to use `Reflect.construct`.

Comment: this method  let Max = Reflect.construct(Name,["Maxi"],greet); same  Name.prototype.greet = n => "Hello" + n;
Did I get right?

Comment: Where is it used?

Comment: Primarily you'd use this when defining custom `Proxy` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is one way for you to achieve what you would like to do with the classes of ES6;

```js
class Name{
    constructor(name)
    {
      this.name = name;
    }
    greet(n){return "Hello " + n;}
}


var Max = new Name("Maxi");
console.log(Max.greet("John"));
```

Comment: and last question  how i call someConstructor with result object 
function someConstructor() {
  return "hello";
}
var result = Reflect.construct(Array, [], someConstructor);